# Using spanned images (.swm) with ImageX /ref switch

Tags: deployment, windows-pe, imagex

I can't seem to find any working examples of usage of the /ref switch with ImageX. Can anyone provide known working syntax?

Answer (score 3):

imagex /apply d:\image.swm /ref d:\image*.swm 1 c:

Comment: What if I have two files *.swm and one *.wim ?
What is the syntax? Or maybe I have apply to three times the same syntax changing only the file name?